# Ruby on Rails 4, stylesheets and pictures

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, web

Im learning Ruby on Rails using a book, based on RoR 3, unfortunately, I see that some things are different since the last update of the framework. I really dont understand how to use CSS files, js plugins and include Pictures. I see that there is three different assets folders and I understand that we use them according to what we want to do? 
Concretely, I'm trying to add a css stylesheet and loading it by the application.html.erb file, to add it to my product page.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go through the `rails asset pipeline`  documentation, which  explains how to place all the assets.

For example Js, Css and Images.
Here is the link to it,

[Rails Asset Pipilining](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

[Other Reference link](https://launchschool.com/blog/rails-asset-pipeline-best-practices)